# How can I decrease the length of video outputted by Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to animate a plot of a system's response over 60 seconds. I have successfully animated the response but the animation is 20 minutes long instead of the 60 seconds I would like. The following block is the relevant code:

```
def animate(i):
    global x, temp_resp_tar, temp_time, temp_resp_tro, temp_resp_pay

    temp_resp_pay = np.append(temp_resp_pay, payload_horiz[i])

    temp_resp_tro = np.append(temp_resp_tro, resp[i,0])

    temp_resp_tar = np.append(temp_resp_tar, resp[i,2])

    temp_time = np.append(temp_time, x[i])

    tar_resp.set_data(temp_time, temp_resp_tar)
    tro_resp.set_data(temp_time, temp_resp_tro)
    pay_resp.set_data(temp_time, temp_resp_pay)



return tar_resp, tro_resp, pay_resp

def init():
    global x
    tar_resp.set_data(x, resp[:,2])
    tro_resp.set_data(x, resp[:,0])
    pay_resp.set_data(x, payload_horiz[:])

return tar_resp, tro_resp, pay_resp


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1, frames=6000, blit=False)



FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
ani.save('response.mp4', writer = FFwriter, fps = 60, extra_args = ['-vodec', 'libx264'])
```

Sorry if this is not the most pythonic code, still in the process of learning. My reasoning behind using 6000 frames is that there are 6000 time samples in the simulation (`np.arange(0,60,0.01)`). I have messed with the interval settings and fps settings with no luck.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Sorry about that, will remember for next time.